# Identify entrypoint file in node.js application using Passenger

Tags: node.js, passenger

My shared host uses Plesk with Phusion Passenger to run node.js applications. I've noticed that `require.main.filename` does not resolve to the application entrypoint configured by the user but to passenger's node-loader (`/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js`) in this environment. So how can you identify the node.js application entrypoint when running with Passenger?

I've already tried using this shim https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-main-filename but unfortunately it returned the same node-loader file.